# Play music with RTP Android

Tags: android, streaming, rtp

It s possible that i can send music data stream on RTP with android mobile.

it's a example for rtp

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-rtp-sample-receiving-via-vlc.html

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html

Comment: Thanks Kanak Sony , kanak i am not able to send music data on rtp from android mobile .